# Tuxguitar - entering verses

Tags: notation, software, tuxguitar

Is there a way to widen the measures in Tuxguitar, so that the words in my song verses don't get cut off or scrunched up?

Answer (score 1):

There's not an obvious way to to lengthen the measures, but you can turn your note value into two smaller ones that are tied like this:

One quarter note:

[image]

Two tied eigth notes:

[image]